# I can't insert hyper link in outlook appointment via c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, rtf

I am using visual studio 2010 and Outlook 2013. I tried to send a hyperlink in my appointment body / rtfbody but I got separate text and url. Here by I was share my code and output.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

oAppointment.Subject = "Enquiry Changes made to " + "Anbuchelvan" + "'s enquiry"; // set the subject
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

rtb.Rtf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oAppointment.RTFBody);
rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength, 0);
rtb.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard {\par} {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK ""http://www.google.com/""}{\fldrslt Click Here}}";

oAppointment.RTFBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtb.Rtf);

// oAppointment.Body =  // set the body
oAppointment.Location = "Nicks Desk!"; // set the location
oAppointment.Start    = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now); // Set the start date 
oAppointment.End      = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now); // End date 
oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
oAppointment.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
oAppointment.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
oAppointment.Recipients.ResolveAll();
oAppointment.Display(true);
oAppointment.Save();
```

My Output is :

> `Click Here <http://www.google.com/>`

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use Office.word.dll

Answer (score 0):

We've had great success with this kind of implementation using HTML.

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Please refer below code.      oAppointment.RTFBody = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>"; throw the  com error                                                                    
            oAppointment.Body = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>";   output like <a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>

Comment: Sorry, I left out the most important part:  oAppointment.HTMLBody= <a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>

Comment: Thanks, But I am using outlook dll 1.15 version. I have only  oAppointment.Body and  oAppointment.RTFBody only. there is no property like  oAppointment.HTMLBody